# how can i add a 3rd condition if last two conditions are satisfied, within Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to add a 3rd condition if the first two conditions are satisfied.

So, I've attached a reference sheet, and here is what I want to do; if a certain email address (from the sheet Attendance) has logged-in on a particular date (login response)- then, in the attendance sheet it should reflect "present" under that particular date.

I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong, or what is it that I'm missing, but I've tried this formula

```
=If(AND(B1=VLOOKUP(B1,'Login response'!D:D,1,0),A2=VLOOKUP(A2,'Login response'!B:B,1,0),"P"))
```

and it doesn't work.

Please see the Google Sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOwruWCLkByn_14Rsc1V4_hixg5JapLKFZ0mOd3BfPs/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your sheet directly.

One formula that works is this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(ArrayFormula(match(B$1&$A2,'Login response'!$D:$D&'Login response'!$B:$B,0))),TRUE,FALSE))
```

And perhaps an even better one is this:

```
=if(countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,C$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A3)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, it works! The 2nd option, I've made a little changes to it; as I want to mark attendance for those email address who used "login" in the "Login Response" sheet- `=if(countifs('Login response'!$D:$D,D$1,'Login response'!$B:$B,$A2,'Login response'!$C:$C,"login")>0,TRUE,FALSE)`